# Construir un array en un foreach

Tags: php

Necesito construir un array en un foreach de la siguiente manera:

```
$opcion_data = [];
foreach ($valores as $valor) {
   // CONSTRUIR AQUI EL ARRAY         
}
```

Necesito que el resultado final sea este:

```
$opcion_data = [
        ['nombre' =>  "valor1"],
        ['nombre' => "valor2"]
    ];
```

Como seria el codigo? Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$opcion_data = [];
foreach ($opciones as $opcion) {
      $opcion_data[]['nombre'] = $opcion;
}
```